# Create Script from Existing Message Type and Queue

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I just started on a project that has an existing set of Service Broker queues and their respective message types, contracts and services.  I would like to re-create these same items on my local machine to test against but I can't find a way to create these exact same items (when I do script -> create from mgmt studio, it doesn't actually give me the innards of structures so creation doesn't work).

Is this possible?  If so, how do I do it?

Comment: What 'innards' are you not seeing? Service Broker scripts contain all the information on the objects.

Comment: By "innards", I meant the actual XML schema used for the messages.  I need to extract that schema somehow so that I can re-create it on my own machine.  If I use mgmt studio, then it just references the schmea collection but I have no idea how to recreate the actual xsd.

Comment: Does [view a XML schema collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191170.aspx) not do what you need?

Comment: @stuartd Thanks for that.  I've gotten too reliant on mgmt studio doing everything for me and was just baffled about how I could re-create the message structure.  Thanks again.